# Round function giving error in pyspark when used with udf

Tags: python, pyspark, rounding

```
def data_preparation(df):

    unlist = udf(lambda x: round(float(list(x)[0]),3), FloatType())
    # Iterating over columns to be scaled
    for i in ["event"]:
        # VectorAssembler Transformation - Converting column to vector type
        assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[i],outputCol=i+"_Vect")

        # MinMaxScaler Transformation
        scaler = MinMaxScaler(inputCol=i+"_Vect", outputCol=i+"_Scaled")

        # Pipeline of VectorAssembler and MinMaxScaler
        pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[assembler, scaler])

        # Fitting pipeline on dataframe
        df = pipeline.fit(df).transform(df).withColumn(i+"_Scaled",unlist(i+"_Scaled")).drop(i+"_Vect")

    return df
```

In above code snippet in the unlist udf i'm trying to take a first element from the list and round it off upto 3 decimal places in. But when i use the function it is giving me error like this:

```
PythonException: 
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 604, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pysparkx/worker.py", line 596, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 211, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 132, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 200, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 450, in mapper
    result = tuple(f(*[a[o] for o in arg_offsets]) for (arg_offsets, f) in udfs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 450, in <genexpr>
    result = tuple(f(*[a[o] for o in arg_offsets]) for (arg_offsets, f) in udfs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-85-a4273b6bc9ab>", line 17, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 1234, in round
    return Column(sc._jvm.functions.round(_to_java_column(col), scale))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

I've tried doing the round operation separately but it is giving me error in the later stages of the program. I'm just looking for the reason for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the line -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

Instead try -

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if you have any null values in the column where you're getting your list from. So I created a sample dataset and applied your code:

```
#THIS ONE WORKS
data = [(1, [3.143412412, 2.444]), (2, [2.718, 0.9090909]), (3, [1.414, 0.12312312321])]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "value"])
unlist = udf(lambda x: round(float(list(x)[0]),3), FloatType())

# Cast the double column to float
df = df.withColumn("value_float", unlist("value"))
```

Then I deliberately changed the data input in id 1 to include a null value at x[0]:

```
#THIS ONE DOESN'T WORKS
data = [(1, [None, 2.444]), (2, [2.718, 0.9090909]), (3, [1.414, 0.12312312321])]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "value"])
unlist = udf(lambda x: round(float(list(x)[0]),3), FloatType())

# Cast the double column to float
df = df.withColumn("value_float", unlist("value"))
```

I don't get the exact same error as you but the presence of a none or a null in your dataset definitely breaks your udf.